# Not able to access the private project created in private group in gitlab

Tags: gitlab

I want to **create a private project in private group** and want to include it as dependency in **a private project created in the same group in gitlab**. What is the procedure for it? I tried generating ssh and linked it. I tried including dependncy like this

`"dependency_name" : "git+ssh://git@domain:groupname/repo.git"`.

I end up with error which says package.json is not found and later I tried creating private repo with outside group (with my user) and tried this

`"dependency_name" : "git+ssh://git@domain:username/repo.git"`

Error:

```
! ssh: connect to host domain.com port 22: Operation timed out
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

End of the day I want to dependency and project to be private. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you try git+ssh://git@domain/username/repo.git with a / instead of :?

Comment: Yes @VonC, I get this error:

`npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t git+ssh://git@domain:username/repo.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ssh: connect to host gir@domain port 22: Connection refused
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128`

Comment: Does `ssh -T git@domain` works (meaning display a "Welcome" message?)

Comment: @VonC it says ssh: connect to host domain port 22: Connection refused

Comment: So you need to resolve that first. Do you have a ~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub) file present in your account?

Comment: @VonC Yes I have created id_rsa_domain.pub. Is that fine or the name should be id_rsa for sure?

Comment: Yes, id_rsa by default, unless you have more than one set of keys.

Comment: It was issue with private git, I did not have necessary permission for the port. With necessary permissions, It works. Thanks for your time @VonC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As confirmed by the OP:

- the URL is `git+ssh://git@domain/username/repo`
- the issue is a permission one on the server side: the user had to be authorized to access that particular repo on the SSH port (it can be sometimes a [client-side firewall issue too](https://serverfault.com/q/189070/783)).